# In a ring, $1-ab$ is invertible $\implies$ $1-ba$ is invertible (from scratch)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, inverse

I know the usual trick: let $c=(1-ab)^{-1}$ and notice that:

$$(1-ba)(bca) = bca - babca = b(c-abc)a=bc(1-ab)a=ba$$

Etc.

I was wondering how to discover this fact from scratch, without invoking this magical observation. Any help in that?

Comment: A slick way is to [use formal power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/675128/242) as below - see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31595/how-would-you-solve-this-tantalizing-halmos-problem) for why it works. $$\begin{eqnarray} \rm (1-ab)^{-1} &=&\rm 1+ ab + a\color{#c00}{ba}b + a\color{#0a0}{baba}b +\,\cdots\\
&=&\rm 1+ a (1\, +\, \color{#c00}{ba}\ \ +\ \ \color{#0a0}{baba}\,\ +\,\cdots)b\\
&=&\rm 1+ a (1\,-\,ba)^{-1}b\end{eqnarray}\qquad\qquad$$   Unless you elaborate, it seems your question is a dupe.

Comment: What's magical about this observation? It's not *obvious*, but it is elementary, in the sense that it doesn't invoke any big heavy-duty theorems.

Comment: @Bill thanks a lot! I don't care what my question seems now, I got what I want.